# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest' in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Receiving following errors

**in Android Studio 2.2**

> Cannot resolve symbol R in Android Studio 2.2

**in gradle console**

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Errors resolving R are usually always problems with the xml resources, in your case it tells you exactly what the problem is, a problem with your manifest file.  See the log.

Comment: but i checked my Xml file , and it has no error according to me

Comment: read error log more carefully, your answer is hidden some where in logs

Comment: mostly this could be originated from xml resource, to fully understand paste full stack trace/logcat ouput,

Comment: Formatted question.

Answer (score 0):

clean your build, and retry? Sometimes I noticed when I switch branches a lot my R.java file is outdated and doesn't get rebuilt correctly or references out of date xml id's.

Answer (score 0):

Just rebuild project and it will be okay, I also have faced alot of times this error